# Importing a library in Python and using it on the same line

Tags: python, python-import

How can I import something in Python and use it on the same line? For example `import random` and using `random.randint(0,10)` on the same line, instead of

```
import random
random.randint(0, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain with `;`.

Like so:

```
import random; random.randint(0, 10)
```

or

```
import random; a = random.randint(0, 10); print(a)
```